# How to click in the link in a herf in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to click in the link in a herf and the link is string

```
<a href="/pages/creation_flow/?step=profile_pic&amp;draft_id=597215097432581&amp;page_id=11020432423337" class="inv" id="u_0_1_sX" data-sigil="no_mpc">تخطي</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it can be done by clicking the element itself.
In case this locator is correct and unique you can do it as following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"/pages/creation_flow/?step=profile_pic")]').click()
```

I can't be sure about the locator since you dint share a link to the page or the entire page HTML.
Also you probably will need to add some delay before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **تخطي** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "تخطي")
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.inv[href^='/pages/creation_flow/?step=profile_pic']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='inv' and starts-with(@href, '/pages/creation_flow/?step=profile_pic')][text()='تخطي']").click()
  ```